# Install a SQL Server database to a client's machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I need to install a SQL Server 2008 database on several user machines.  The users are not technically proficient, so I cannot create a script and just give it to them.  I need to be able to create an executable that will create the database.  The executable will check if the user has SQL Server 2008 Express installed, then install the database.  The executable will install the database using Integrated Security, so I don't need the user's id or password.

I tried using the database project in Visual Studio 2010, but it just creates scripts.

Is there an open source solution to creating an executable that installs SQL Server databases?

Comment: On each user machine?  Why not just go with sqlite3?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you look at embedding SQLServer 2008 Express within your application.

Check the Microsoft link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd981032%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx).

Then you can check for an SQL instance and install one if it doesn't exist when the program first starts up.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to use SQL [Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) to create a .NET console application that creates the database.

Depending on your security rights on your user's machines you may be able to run the app from your workstation and deploy directly to their machines.

SMO can also be driven by powershell.